# Deploying a statefulSet with static volume provisioning but controller insists to use dynamic

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-volume, persistent-volumes

I am trying to deploy a statefulSet that will use *static* volume provisioning (claim existing PVs) based on their label. However, it seems that the persistentvolume-controller is trying to provision storage *dynamically*, as when I `kubectl desribe pvc db-data-db-N` the Events log states that:

```
Events:
  Type       Reason              Age               From                         Message
  ----       ------              ----              ----                         -------
  Warning    ProvisioningFailed  9s (x3 over 21s)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "db-data-storage": claim.Spec.Selector is not supported for dynamic provisioning on AWS
```

I have pre-provisioned PVs with this format (I am using Helm):

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: db-data-{{ $volIndex }}
  labels:
    restoredFromBackup: "true"
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    volumeID: {{ $volId }}
    fsType: ext4
```

Here is my PVC template:

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: db-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 30Gi
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          restoredFromBackup: "true"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try by specifying a storageClassName since Kubernetes will be using default storage class when it's not specified?
See [Dynamic Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/03/dynamic-provisioning-and-storage-classes-kubernetes/) of the blog post and [Dynamic](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) from Kubernetes documentation?
Or try with by removing the default storageclass in the cluster to explicitly use given PV and PVC configuration.

Comment: Thank you, this was the case - the Cluster had a default StorageClass which was getting used and forcing the PVC to be dynamic. Once I configured there to be no default storageClass then the issue was resolved.

Comment: Good to know that was the issue, please accept the answer if you will.

Comment: I didn't mark it (yet) because the first part is misleading, implying that a StorageClass is required. "Did you try by specifying a storageClassName".

Comment: Ok, I will edit the answer to add clarity about removing the default SC.